# Why does (true && {}) evaluate to {}, but ({} && true) evaluates to true?

Tags: javascript, boolean, boolean-logic

As the title said, I can't quite understand why (true && {}) gives me {}, but the reverse is not the same.

Edit: As a followup, since I'm using a boolean operator, why does this expression not give me a boolean when evaluated?

Comment: The JavaScript `&&` and `||` operators do not give boolean values. They're different from the similar operators in Java and C etc.  They return the value of one or the other of their operands.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The expression operands to `&&` are evaluated left to right. The value of the `&&` expression is the value of the subexpression last evaluated. In your case, that'll be the right-most expression in both cases.

So, with `(true && {})`, the `&&` operator first evaluates `true`. It's not falsy, so it then evaluates `{}` and returns that expression result.

With  `({} && true)` it does the same things backwards, so the second expression evaluated is `true`.

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks! (I'll accept the answer when enough time has passed, SO won't let me accept one so quickly).

Answer (score 0):

`a && b`will return `a` if `a` is falsy, otherwise `b`.

Indeed, if `a` is falsy (such as `''`, `null`, `undefined`, `0`), javascript doesn't need to evaluate the rest of the expression as it is `false` anyway. However it doesn't return `false`, but the first **falsy** value. However if `a` is truthy, it need to evaluate the rest in order to know the result of the expression.

You have the opposite logic when using `||`.

Now in your example, `{}` is truthy, so

```
(true && {}) // {}
({} && true) // true
({} && true && 42 && '' && true && {}) // '' as first falsy value
```

Comment: Why would using boolean operators not give me a boolean when evaluated, though?

Comment: Because that's how Javascript is made, it avoids to create yeat another boolean value by just returning to you the one that has the truthy/falsy value you expect. You can use `!!val` to get the real boolean value out of a truthy/falsy though.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to truthy and falsy logic in JavaScript. All objects that are not: `undefined`, `null`, `false` or `0` are truthy. The `&&` and `||` operands are evaluated left to right and short-circuit. The expression evaluates to the value of the last evaluated operand. eg:

```
true && false // will evaluate to false
true || false // will evaluate to true
```